# how to memorized the array values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function in which I build an array. 
To this array I apply the shift function, so the array at the end is empty.
What I need to do is to save the values of the array before it becomes empty.
I tried to save the values in another array but I don't undersantd why but it doesn't function ad I expect.
The code is the following:

```
  function tableHeadersToArray(Firstheader_fields, header_fields){

        //- Put all header1 > td elements in a collection
        var row1tds = Firstheader_fields;

        //I define the variable at the beginning of my javascript code before the function
        //var header1Colspans = [];
        //var pippo = [];
        // var indice;  

        //at the first run indice will be 1     
        if(indice ==2){
           header1Colspans=pippo;           
        }else{
           indice =1;
        }

        if(indice==1){      
          for(var index=0; index<row1tds.length; index++){               
             header1Colspans.push(row1tds[index].getAttribute('colspan') || 1);
          //in this way I assign to pippo the values of header1Colspans
             pippo = header1Colspans;
          }
            indice=2;
        }

        //- Put all header2 > td elements in a collection
          var row2tds = header_fields;

        //- This is the tricky part
        //- Draw 2 arrays, one below the other on a pice of paper
        //- and place your 2 index fingers at the beginning of each one.
        //- Your left index finger is index1, and your right is index2.
        //- Follow the code, and each time one is incremented, move it
        //- to the right one cell.

        var colspan, index1=0, index2=0, resultingArray=[];

        //- (colspan = header1Colspans.shift()) gets the first element of the array,
        //- assigns it to var colspan and the expression has the value TRUE if the
        //- assignment was made, or FALSE if there were no more elements in the array
        while(index1 < row1tds.length && (colspan = header1Colspans.shift())){
          while(index2 < row2tds.length && colspan > 0){                   
             var Value1=row1tds[index1].textContent;
             var LenghtVal=Value1.length;

        //- Here we concatenate 'ROME' + '-' + 'CITIES' and add it to the array
        // - In case the Header1 is blank we don't concatenate the values
             if(LenghtVal > 1){                  
                 resultingArray.push(row1tds[index1].textContent + ' - ' + 
                  row2tds[index2].textContent);
              }else{                     
                 resultingArray.push(row2tds[index2].textContent);
               }
              index2++;
              colspan--;
             }
           index1++;
        }
      return resultingArray;    
    }
```

When I open my HTML page the function is executed so the header1Colspans at the end of the function is empty. Then when I click on a button that I have on my html table the function is executed again and the array is populated each time with the new colspan attribute (in another function i  need to change the values of the colspan). The point is that in this function  I want just the values of the first time the function is executed so i want take the original colspan values. For this reason I have created the array pippo, because I thought to save the values there and then to use just pippo but it doesn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 arrays in JavaScript, `a` and `b`, `b = a` will make `b` a reference to `a`. Example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = a;

console.log(b);
// It will print [1, 2, 3, 4]

// Let's remove the last element of 'a':
a.pop();

console.log(b);
// It will print [1, 2, 3], because 'b' is a reference to 'a'
```

That said, you cannot clone an array like in the example. Fortunately there are alternatives, see some examples below. You need to use that line before you use the `shift()` in your array. I will not explain them here, but you can use the one that suits you best:

```
var myCopyOfTheArray = header1Colspans.slice(0);
var myCopyOfTheArray = header1Colspans.map(x => x);
var myCopyOfTheArray = header1Colspans.filter(() => true);
var myCopyOfTheArray = [...header1Colspans];
```

Comment: You could also use the spread operator `var myCopy = [...header1Colspans]`

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer! I used the slice and it works as  I expected, but just the first time the function is executed. The second time pippo which is my b becomes empty. -.-'

Comment: Hi @Dana. I noticed you did not initialize the `pippo` variable. Try adding `var pippo;` in the beginning (inside) of your function. If you do not use `var` (or `let`, or `const`) the variable is created in the global scope instead of the function scope. I believe this is the reason for your problem. You can find a detailed explanation here: https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/

Comment: no it is not the problem, if  i add pippo inside the function each time the function is called I lost the value of pippo. The value of pippo should be set the first time and i need to mantain it each time the function is called. for this reason I initialize the variable outside the function. thanks for your help

Comment: ok i fixed the problem by using the slice each time i need to assign the values to my array. I had other parts i the code in which i continued using pippo= header1Colspans so I  lost the values. Using everywhere the slice it work perfectly! Thanks again for the collaboration